# Regex in KornShell

Tags: regex, shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to check whether a variable is exactly two numbers but I can not seem to figure it out.

How do you do check regular expressions (regex) in KornShell (ksh)?

I have tried:

```
if [[ $month =~ "[0-9]{2}" ]]
if [[ $month = _[0-9]{2}_ ]]
```

I have not been able to find any docs on it.

Any insight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
case $month in
    [0-9][0-9]) echo "ok";;
    *) echo "no";;
esac
```

should work.

If you need full regexp search, you can use `egrep` like this:

```
if echo $month | egrep -q '^[0-9]{2}$'
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Comment: While using egrep will work, it is an external program and will slow down the script a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Ksh has supported limited extended patterns since ksh88, using the

```
special '(' pattern ')'
```

syntax.

In ksh88, the 'special' character prefixes change the number of matches expected:

```
'*' for zero or more matches
'+' at least one match
'@' for exactly one match
'?' for zero or one matches
'!' for negation
```

In ksh93, this was expanded with

```
'{' min ',' max '}'
```

to express an exact range:

```
for w in 1423 12 "" abc 23423 9 33 3  333
do
  [[ $w == {1,3}(\d) ]] && print $w has between 1 and three digits
  [[ $w == {2}(\d) ]] && print $w has exactly two digits
done
```

And finally, you can have perl-like clutter with '~', which introduces a whole new class of extensions,including full regular expressions with:

'~(E)( regex )'

More examples can be found in [Finnbarr P. Murphy's blog](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/01/ksh93-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: You don't need the ~(E) if you use =~, that's the default

Answer (score 5):

Where I come from, this is more likely to validate numeric months:

```
if (( $month >= 1 && $month <= 12 ))
```

or

```
[[ $month =~ ^([1-9]|1[012])$ ]]
```

or to include a leading zero for single-digit months:

```
[[ $month =~ ^(0[1-9]|1[012])$ ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

ksh does not use regular expressions; it uses a simpler but still quite useful language called "shell globbing patterns".  The key ideas are

- Classes like `[0-9]` or `[chly]` match any character in the class.
- The `.` is not a special character; it matches only `.`.
- The `?` matches any single character.
- The `*` matches any sequence of characters.
- Unlike regular expressions, shell globbing patterns must match the *entire* word, so it works as if it were a regexp it would always start with `^` and end with `$`.

Globbing patterns are not as powerful as regular expressions, but they are much easier to read, and they are very convenient for matching filenames and simple words.  The `case` construct is my favorite for matching but there are others.

As already noted by Alok you probably want

```
case $number in
  [0-9][0-9]) success ;;
  *) failure;;
esac
```

Although possibly you might prefer not to match a two-digit number with initial zero, so prefer `[1-9][0-9]`.

Comment: ksh93 supports both basic and extended regular expressions using the binding operator =~

Comment: +1 for explaining the key differences between regexes and patterns; @cdarke: that's good to know, but I can't get it to support _interval_ expressions such as `{2}`; e.g. `[[ 11 =~ [0-9]{2} ]] && echo YES` causes a syntax error; `\`-escaping the braces results in no match; am I missing something (`ksh 93u`)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this as well

```
$ month=100
$ [[ $month == {1,2}([0-9]) ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
$ [[ $month == [0-9][0-9] ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
$ month=10
$ [[ $month == {1,2}([0-9]) ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
ok
$ [[ $month == [0-9][0-9] ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
ok
```