# ksh IP address pattern

Tags: regex, shell, ksh

Trying to match $1 to see if it's an IP address in ksh.

```
if [ $1 = "^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$" ]
```

doesn't seem to be identifying the following

```
ksh -x samp.sh 192.168.128.10
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121394/regex-in-korn-shell

Comment: Use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` and `=~` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
"[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Ksh only [has a subset of regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121394/regex-in-korn-shell?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Thanks didn't go well. Had no time and did it in bash. :(

Answer (score 0):

I used the following regular expression evaluation in KSH93 and it worked for me.

```
if [[ $1 == {1,3}(\d).{1,3}(\d).{1,3}(\d).{1,3}(\d) ]]
then
# regex expression evaluated to true
<< perform some action here .... >>
else
# regex expression evaluated to false
<< perform some action here .... >>
fi
```