# Unix KornShell script boolean inside a function to check a phone number

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I wrote this script in Unix:

```
function addinfo {
  echo "Please enter your LAST Name: "
  read last
  echo "Please enter your FIRST Name: "
  read first
  echo "Please enter your PHONE number as XXX-XXX-XXXX: "
  read phone
  if [ $phone != ???-???-??? ]; then
    echo "Please only enter your as XXX-XXX-XXXX"
    read phone
  else
    echo $last + $first + $phone >> asg7phonebook
  if
}
```

I'm getting an error code associated with the last bracket.

1. Can boolean conditions work inside a Unix function?
2. How do I get my function to check whether the user entered `XXX-XXX-XXXX` (where "X" is their phonenumber) as a valid number input? I want to prevent the user from entering `23435-3422`2 as their number or 1234567890 as their number.
3. Is my syntax correct?

Comment: It's a korn script in Unix but can work in Linux (I suppose) if Korn is installed.

Comment: Elliott, thanks for the help. Yeah, it's a korn shell, sorry.

Comment: You need to end with `fi`, not `if`.

Comment: your last "if" should be "fi"

Comment: Also, use `addinfo() {` to start a function, not `function addinfo {`, unless you know why you're doing otherwise.

Comment: Another POSIX-compliant way to check: `case $phone in ???-???-?????) echo "$last + $first + $phone" >> asg7phonebook ;; *) echo "Please only enter your as XXX-XXX-XXXX"; read phone;; esac`

Comment: STUPID MISTAKE.  I HAVE "IF" AS OPPOSED TO "FI" AT THE END. THE SCRIPT RUNS FINE NOW (>_<)

Comment: please make question as ANSWERED.

Comment: @autoVox, you, as the person asking the question, are the person who can accept an answer; click on the green check mark next to the one you prefer. Also, just because your code "works" with that fix alone doesn't mean you can't benefit / learn from some of the other answers given.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you. I did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few issues with your approach,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

addinfo() {
  echo "Please enter your LAST Name: "
  read last
  echo "Please enter your FIRST Name: "
  read first
  echo "Please enter your PHONE number as XXX-XXX-XXXX: "
  read phone
  # Using a while loop on the correct pattern check.
  while [[ "$phone" != [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]
  do
      echo "Please enter your PHONE number as XXX-XXX-XXXX (only): "
      read phone
  done
  echo $last + $first + $phone >> asg7phonebook
}

addinfo
```

Comment: Why the gratuitously non-POSIX `function funcname {` syntax? Sure, it works, but it has no benefit over the standards-compliant form.

Comment: ...also, use of a pattern on the RHS of `!=` isn't POSIX-standard for `[`, but is explicitly using a ksh92 facility when within `[[ ]]`.

Comment: The conditional won't work as intended; as @CharlesDuffy hints at, you need `[[` and you mustn't double-quote the pattern; i.e.: `if [[ "$phone" != [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]`

Comment: Indeed, thanks; and thanks for adding the validation loop. +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
function addinfo() {
  echo "Please enter your LAST Name: "
  read last
  echo "Please enter your FIRST Name: "
  read first
  echo "Please enter your PHONE number as XXX-XXX-XXXX: "
  read phone
  if [[ $phone =~ ^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$ ]]; then
    echo $last:$first:$phone >> asg7phonebook
  else
    echo "Please only enter your as XXX-XXX-XXXX"
  fi
}

addinfo
```

Comment: this is explicitly a ksh script, not a bash script. (Sure, they're close, _but_)

Comment: I suggest you read carefully the comments to the original post clarifying the OP's intent.

Comment: As I said, "The Original Post" my answer was in regard to that.

Comment: I suggest you preface your answer saying (explicitly) that (a) it is a **bash** solution and that (b) it is so because the OP initially didn't make it clear that he/she was looking for a **ksh** solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Elliott Frisch's answer is a working solution, but just to show a **simpler matching** option using `ksh 93`'s **extended patterns**:

```
[[ $phone == {3}(\d)-{3}(\d)-{4}(\d) ]]  # matches '123-456-7890', for instance
```

<sup>Courtesy of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523776/45375</sup>